# Below command works on android flutter but not working with ios flutter

Tags: flutter, ffmpeg, flutter-ffmpeg

This below command is properly working for android flutter but not working on ios flutter ..
It is a link of command ffmpeg can you check it and resolve it

https://docs.google.com/document/d/114edgC9a9c30R5DM_thj_zxfsvN8e0XoRlqzI1LzGOQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please edit and write perfect code here so we will understand.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/114edgC9a9c30R5DM_thj_zxfsvN8e0XoRlqzI1LzGOQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.